# load all images from internal memory to a viewPager android

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager, picasso

i have designed an app to show images in a view Pager, now the thing is that user saves this images to its internal memory and the app gives a random no. to the image as name, upon clicking "View Favorite " button the user gets to view all the images in a view pager one by one, can any1 help me as to how i go about it??

```
private void loadImageFromStorage(String path)
{

    try {

        File f=new File(path, "image.png");
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        Context context =getApplicationContext();
         final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
          R.dimen.padding_medium);
      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
     imageView.setImageBitmap(b);

    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this is the code to load the image but the thing is i need to load all the images not just one image.png but everything.png ;) how do i do it??
 and also i wanna load with Picasso but i cant load the bitmap it says something like load is not for bitmap etc. etc. please help

Comment: If you just took the effeort to browse/search this site for 'displaying images from sdcard' or like that, you would find examples.

Comment: @greenapps please provide useful comments instead of saying something like this sounds 3rd grade but thanks nevertheless

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have already solved this issue. But if you don't give your files a random number when you save them, you could give them sequential numbers like 1.jpg, 2.jpg .... then you could do a while loop to load each image. For example:

```
int counter = 0;
    boolean imageExists = true;

    while(imageExists)
    {
        File imageFile = new File (filePath + counter + ".jpg");
        if(imageFile.exists())
        {
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(imgFile).fit().centerInside().into(imageView);
        }
        else
        {
            imageExists = false;
        }

    }
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: thanks but i have solved it using universal image loader, picasso not for me